# SIM card not detecting after android 5.1 update moto g 1st gen

Tags: motorola-moto-g, 5.1-lollipop

I updated  my 1st Gen moto g today but after that the phone is not detecting  the SIM card. I have  tried with other cards too but it won't work.

EDIT: Its system default update for lollipop 5.1

Answer (score 0):

Was this an official update or a custom rom you flashed yourself? If it's an official build,  then the manufacturers would soon come up with a fix.  If you flashed a custom rom yourself maybe you should check the blog where from you downloaded the rom to see if other users too have the same problem.  In the meanwhile you may try a factory reset.

Comment: For a temporary fix I am now using the second sim slot since the phone has dual sim support.